# QGIS: Authentication System: Resources

Tags: qgis

[image]

I tried to delete and redownload QGIS 3.8 and now I can not make new projects on QGIS because of this error message:

> **Authentication System**: DISABLED. Resources authenticating via the system can not be accessed.

Is there anyway to get rid of it the error message so I can work on projects in QGIS? I already have Python and GDAL installed from before.

Comment: Try renaming the QGIS3 folder - http://planet.qgis.org/planet/user/3/tag/qgis3

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and wondered if it is because of some new updates a few days ago. My QGIS is installed view osgeo and homebrew; I came across g-sherman's response on issue [#197](https://github.com/OSGeo/homebrew-osgeo4mac/issues/197#issuecomment-367426473), relinked my osgeo-qgis installation, and then opened it from the terminal instead of Spotlight (this actually didn't work before), and now this error is gone.

In summary, if your case is the same as mine:

- Open Terminal.app
- Run `brew relink osgeo-qgis`
- Start up QGIS through `osgeo-qgis`